# I want change bezier curve's endpoint

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, bezier

Sorry for my paint:

[image: img]

I want change bezier curve's endpoint

start from s point with control points(c1, c2) to end point

when point arrive at changepoint(pink), I want change endpoint and

get the new path for new endpoint smoothly

How ? help me..

Comment: Hi what have you tried yet?

Comment: @AnindyaDutta I don't understand what you says...

Comment: 너 뭐 해봤 니? 당신이 직면 한 문제는 무엇입니까?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your question but I have crated a simpl program which will let u understand bezier curves.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>A simple tool</title>

 <style type="text/css">
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .controlButton {
  border: 0;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1px;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
 }

 #mainCanvas {
  background: #FFF;
 }

 #output {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Monospace;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="controlWrapper">
  <button class="controlButton" onclick="activePoint='sp'" id="sp">Start Point</button>
  <button class="controlButton" onclick="activePoint='cp1'" id="cp1">Control Point 1</button>
  <button class="controlButton" onclick="activePoint='cp2'" id="cp2">Control Point 2</button>
  <button class="controlButton" onclick="activePoint='ep'" id="ep">End Point</button>
 </div>
 <canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
 <div id="output"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var width = canvas.width = innerWidth;
 var height = canvas.height = innerHeight;

 var activeCurve = {
  sp:  { x: width/2, y: height/2 },
  cp1: { x: width/2+50, y: height/2+100 },
  cp2: { x: width/2+200, y: height/2+100 },
  ep:  { x: width/2+200, y: height/2+50 }
 };

 var activePoint = "";

 addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  switch(activePoint) {
   case "sp":
    activeCurve.sp.x = e.clientX;
    activeCurve.sp.y = e.clientY;
    break;
   case "cp1":
    activeCurve.cp1.x = e.clientX;
    activeCurve.cp1.y = e.clientY;
    break;
   case "cp2":
    activeCurve.cp2.x = e.clientX;
    activeCurve.cp2.y = e.clientY;
    break;
   case "ep":
    activeCurve.ep.x = e.clientX;
    activeCurve.ep.y = e.clientY;
    break;
  }
 });

 addEventListener("click", function() {
  activePoint = "";
 }, true)

 function draw() {
  var sp = document.getElementById("sp");
  sp.style.top = activeCurve.sp.y + "px";
  sp.style.left = activeCurve.sp.x  + "px";

  var cp1 = document.getElementById("cp1");
  cp1.style.top = activeCurve.cp1.y + "px";
  cp1.style.left = activeCurve.cp1.x  + "px";

  var cp2 = document.getElementById("cp2");
  cp2.style.top = activeCurve.cp2.y + "px";
  cp2.style.left = activeCurve.cp2.x  + "px";

  var ep = document.getElementById("ep");
  ep.style.top = activeCurve.ep.y + "px";
  ep.style.left = activeCurve.ep.x  + "px";

  var o = document.getElementById("output");
  o.innerHTML = "<i>context</i>.moveTo(" + activeCurve.sp.x + ", " + activeCurve.sp.y +");<br/><i>context</i>.bezierCurveTo(" 
   + activeCurve.cp1.x + "," 
   + activeCurve.cp1.y + "," 
   + activeCurve.cp2.x + "," 
   + activeCurve.cp2.y + ","
   + activeCurve.ep.x  + "," 
   + activeCurve.ep.y +  ");";

  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#289e82";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#16614f";
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;

  ctx.moveTo(activeCurve.sp.x, activeCurve.sp.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(
   activeCurve.cp1.x, activeCurve.cp1.y, 
   activeCurve.cp2.x, activeCurve.cp2.y,
   activeCurve.ep.x, activeCurve.ep.y);

  ctx.stroke()
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#101010";
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;

  ctx.moveTo(activeCurve.sp.x, activeCurve.sp.y);
  ctx.lineTo(activeCurve.cp1.x, activeCurve.cp1.y);
  ctx.moveTo(activeCurve.ep.x, activeCurve.ep.y);
  ctx.lineTo(activeCurve.cp1.x, activeCurve.cp1.y);

  ctx.moveTo(activeCurve.sp.x, activeCurve.sp.y);
  ctx.lineTo(activeCurve.cp2.x, activeCurve.cp2.y);
  ctx.moveTo(activeCurve.ep.x, activeCurve.ep.y);
  ctx.lineTo(activeCurve.cp2.x, activeCurve.cp2.y);

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore();

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
 }

 draw()
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

click to select a control point

Answer (score 0):

So if I got it right you want to change control point `E` but still want that your curve goes through the same pink point. There are several ways to achieve this. For example you could duplicate the change point as a control point. For cubics using triple control point will force the curve to go through it. for more info on stacking up cubics see:

- [piecewise cubics call sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20517874/2521214)

However using approximation polynomials will be always problematic for this kind of task. Why not use interpolation polynomial instead. So convert **BEZIER** control points to interpolation cubic (so that change point is one of the control points) then change `E` and convert back to **BEZIER** control points (in case you can render only **BEZIER**). The transformation between **BEZIER** and interpolation cubics is here:

- [BEZIER vs. interpolation cubic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214)

Also as your change point is not one of the control points then you can make it one by:

- [Split a cubic bezier curve at multiple points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33934745/2521214)