# Decompose one Path.cubicTo call into two

Tags: flutter, math, graphics, bezier, cubic-bezier

I have a path that I am drawing between two points using a single call [Path.cubicTo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/cubicTo.html). I now have the requirement to have that path drawn in two path segment based on a variable position in the path.

I need the path to look like the original single cubicTo call, but I need to have it actually be two separate calls between two separate sets of points?

My ultimate goal is to have to path look identical to the single call, but with the exception that a variable amount of the path is drawn in a different color.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a cubic Bézier curve at a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991702/split-a-cubic-b%c3%a9zier-curve-at-a-point)

Comment: check `PathMetric` class - it has `extractPath` method

Comment: @pskink PathMetric does not have an extractPath method, and I don't know how this applies to the problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: yes, it has `extractPath` method, check flutter official [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/index.html)